# Many users in account and app integration

Tags: docusignapi

When performing authorization code grant authentication, Docusign asks for consent. Far as I understand documentation, it's user's consent implied. When first asked for consent, the user is required to enter his credentials. When asked next time, the same user is implied.

However consider this: I have 3 users listed in my demo account wowproj.dev@gmail.com: the wowproj.dev@gmail.com himself, and Mary@inbox.ru, and Mike@inbox.ru.

I need to know two things:

1) whether I can statically specify the user when doing code authorization (say, by his "api username"), so that the user only has to press some "OK" button (maybe enter his password as well, but not username) - is that possible? Otherwise it may be possible that I have users "Mike" and "Mary" in my app, and I have those users in my Docusign account as well; then "Mike" user of my application starts some action, but when asked for consent, "Mary" enters her Docusign credentials and gives her consent. I want the consent to be Mike's! For example, I could store Mike's api username in his account in my app, and use it in grant authorization. But, far as I can see, neither user's login nor his api username are sent to Docusign in authorization code request, so I don't see how to achieve what I want.

2) *When asked next time, the same user is implied* - that may be a problem. What if my "Mike" from former paragraph, when asked by Docusign, enters his credentials and gives his consent, then he logs out from MY application and Mary logs in instead and starts some action involving Docusign; will Docusign assume it's still Mike's session? How do I make sure this does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your question's use of "implied." Here's how it works. If you have further questions, please update (edit) your original question.

When using authorization code grant, the user first authenticates himself to DocuSign.

Then, if he hasn't previously done so, he is asked to grant consent to the integration. The permissions requested by the integration are the integration's **scopes**. The usual scope is **signature**, there can be others.

After he grants consent, the DocuSign authorization service will redirect the user's browser back to the integration, and and an authorization code will be included as a query parameter.

Your integration then makes an oauth call to DocuSign to exchange the authorization code for an access token.

Next (typically), your integration uses the [OAuth::getUserInfo](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/user-info-endpoints) method to obtain the user's name, email, authorized DocuSign accounts, and more from DocuSign.

### Ensuring that your app's user is the DocuSign user

You can't force who will be authenticating with DocuSign. But you can check that the right person authenticated. For example:

1. Mike logs into your app. You know Mike's email.
2. Your app wants its user to authenticate with DocuSign. Your app initiates the OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow with DocuSign.
3. Your app's user now sees the DocuSign login screen.
4. (The problem) is that Mike asks Mary to authenticate with DocuSign for him. Mary does so.
5. But when your app learns the email address of the DocuSign authenticated user, it will be Mary's email address, not Mike's. So your app can reject the DocuSign authentication by posting a message to the user saying that **Mike** must re-authenticate with DocuSign.

By implementing the above, your app can guarantee that when Mike is logged into your app, the matching authentication with DocuSign will be Mike's DocuSign user account, never someone else's.

Instead of comparing email addresses, you can also use the DocuSign user id. But doing so requires that you go through a step of loading your app with a table that associates Mike's account and his DocuSign User ID. Email addresses are probably easier.

### Re: other people logging in after a prior session

There are two cases:

#### Same browser on the same machine

This is the "public computer problem."

Mike uses browser "G" to login into your app and also into DocuSign. Later Mary slides into his seat and uses the same browser and same application.

By default, DocuSign's OAuth Auth Code Grant enables Silent Authentication. This means that the DocuSign auth flow will silently enable Mary to use Mike's DocuSign session (if it is still active). For a public machine scenario, this is obviously not good. Solutions:

1. Always require DocuSign to actively authenticate the person (no Silent Authentication allowed). To do so, include `prompt=login` in the initial URL sent to DocuSign. See [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant).
2. Clear the browser's cookies between users. The standard methods for handling public computers will include this.

#### Different users on the same app

Your app should use sessions. Each user of the app (in parallel or sequentially) will get their own session. Each session should maintain its own authentication information for DocuSign including the current user's access token, account id, and base url.

All of that information is determined as part of the authentication-with-DocuSign process.

These days, all modern web app frameworks provide easy to use session interfaces.

We also have code examples you can use. [See this repository list.](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=eg-03&type=&language=) (With more on the way.)

Comment: "Clear the browser's cookies between users." - ok, so it's where Docusign stores its session information. Basically what I needed to know. Could you please also give me some reference to its documentation saying that? So that I could be sure not purely from empirical observation.

Comment: DocuSign authentication will ignore the cookie if you turn off Silent Authentication. Documentation of this issue is by inference--see the Silent Authentication info on this [page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)